# How to fix "NoClassDefFoundError" for a package inside a package

Tags: java, package, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

Java Program

File Location : ..\new1\packageEG\B.java

```
package packageEG ;
public class B
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("B") ;
    }
}
```

File Location : ..\new1\C.java

```
package new1 ;
import packageEG.B ;
public class C 
{
    public void display()
    {
        B b = new B() ;
        b.display() ;
    }
}
```

File Location : ..\A.java

```
import new1.C ;
public class A 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        C c = new C() ;
        c.display() ;
    }
}
```

Folder View

```
../
   A.java
   new1/
      C.java
      packageEG/
            B.java
```

It has nested package, one package inside another package.

When I compile main class i.e, "A" it compiles successfully but when I run this program it shows following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: packageEG/B
        at new1.C.display(C.java:7)
        at A.main(A.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packageEG.B
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 2 more
```

Please help me how to fix this error.

Comment: Do you have all these classes in same module? Is it possible to share a reproducer project ?

Comment: I mentioned file location before every code snippet, for simplicity I added folder view. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem will be to restructure your directories. It is a good practice to store source files and classes in separate directories, typically "src" and "classes". Then compile using `--class-path` option.

For your case as an example we can consider the structure of your project as (we may also put `A.java` in `src` directory but to maintain some similarity with your code structure let us consider this):

```
tree
.
├── A.java
└── src
    └── com
        └── xyz
            ├── B.java
            └── C.java
```

To compile the source using JDK, we need to use the `-d` option to specify the base directory of the compiled classes, i.e. `classes`, as follows:

`javac -d classes src/com/xyz/B.java src/com/xyz/C.java`

Now compile `A.java` using `-cp` or `--class-path` option to specify the base directory of the package `com.xyz` in order to locate `com.xyz.C`.

```
javac -cp ./classes/ A.java
```

Now the directory structure will be like:

```
tree
.
├── A.class
├── A.java
├── classes
│   └── com
│       └── xyz
│           ├── B.class
│           └── C.class
└── src
    └── com
        └── xyz
            ├── B.java
            └── C.java
```

To run, explicitly set `CLASSPATH` variable to include current directory (denoted using '.') in the `CLASSPATH` together with base directory of the package `com.xyz` separated by ':' on linux or ';' on windows.
Linux:

```
java -cp .:./classes A
```

Windows:

```
java -cp .;d:\path\to\directory\classes A
```